# MS SQL dts to ssis migration error

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server

I have migrated some DTS packages to SSIS 2005 using "Migration" wizard. When I tried to run it, it fails saying you need a higher version of SSIS even though the destination SSIS server is on 9.0.4211 level.

then I digged in the package using business intelligence studio and saw that one of the package subtasks is "Transform data task" (the dts version) and the package fails to run that.
The storage location for this dts task is set to "Embedded in Task". I didn't touch it.

why didn't it convert this task to an SSIS data flow task?

any help please?

Thansk in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per BOL the migration component only migrated what it can...not 100%. The client machine had to have ssis installed. and then i used config files.